# Proxy that can handle offline requests

Tags: open-source, proxy

Recently I have come across [Bassa](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/bassa), a proxy having useful capabilities, such as download user defined size files over off-peak hours.

From http://www.slideshare.net/wathsalav/bassa-presentation:

> When ever they try to download a file which is larger than a given threshold the Proxy server will redirect him to Bassa web interface, from there onwards Bassa will take control of the download. If the file already exists in Bassa cache then user will get the file instead of being redirected to Bassa web interface.

Unfortunately it looks like they are not supporting or maintaining or updating it (last update: 2013-04-17).

Do I have any alternative that can be used for above requirement that are used by system/network admins?

My goal is to preserve peak bandwidth and let users download bigger files in offpeak hours without adding direct restriction.